# Python3 import error smart_unicode django

Tags: python, django, python-import, importerror

This is my first time ever trying to run a py script

I have a script to auto import to android studio some translations. I installed python 3.10.5 and pip and trying to run a script. I also installed Django 4.0.5

I have this import `from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, smart_unicode`

When i try to run it, I get the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'smart_unicode' from 'django.utils.encoding' (C:\Users\a816353\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py)
```

I have tried some suggestions but I cant figure out what to do.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the version of Django? IMHO `smart_unicode` was removed from Django a long time ago.

Comment: @Matthias added version. What is this import replaced from then? Should I downgrade Django instead?

Comment: As far as I can see `smart_unicode` was removed in Django 2. So if you have a project that depends on Django 1 you will have to downgrade to an unsupported Django 1. The better option would be to adjust the code in the project, so that it will run with a current version of Django.

Comment: ty, I ll try that. I was wondering though, since smart_unicode is deprecated, which method replaced it.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Your code was written for, and will only run on, Python 2 and Django 1.x. For Python 3 and all later versions of Django (2.0+), the function `smart_unicode` should be replaced by [`smart_str`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.smart_str), and any old uses of `smart_str` should be replaced by [`smart_bytes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.smart_bytes).

---

The `smart_*` functions from `django.utils.encoding` have evolved quit a bit throughout Django's history.

Back in Python 2, Django had two functions, `smart_str` and `smart_unicode`, which corresponded to Python 2's `str` and `unicode` types. In Python 2, `str` represented an arbitrarily encoded sequence of bytes, while `unicode` represented a sequence of Unicode codepoints. However, when Python 3 came along, [string representation in Python changed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit). The builtins `str` and `unicode` were replaced by `bytes` and `str`, where `bytes` represents an arbitrary sequence of bytes (what `str` modeled in Python 2), and `str` represents a Unicode string (what `unicode` modeled in Python 2).  Correspondingly, [Django 1.4 renamed the functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/python3/#string-handling) `smart_str` and `smart_unicode` to `smart_bytes` and `smart_text` respectively. For backwards compatibility, Python 2 releases of Django 1.x kept `smart_unicode` as an alias for `smart_text` and `smart_str` as an alias of `smart_bytes`. Meanwhile, Python 3 releases of Django 1.x [dropped `smart_unicode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.encoding) entirely and made `smart_str` an alias of `smart_text`.

When Django 2.0 was released, support for Python 2 was dropped, so the name `smart_unicode` ceased to exist entirely. This left `smart_str` and `smart_text` as being equivalent names for what `smart_unicode` used to be.

In Django 3.0 [`smart_text` was deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/3.0/#features-deprecated-in-3-0), and [then removed in Django 4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-4-0). These days, `smart_str` is the appropriate equivalent for what `smart_unicode` used to be.

---

Since the code you're working with includes reference to `smart_unicode`, it must have been written for Django 1.x. If you want to make it work as-in, you'll need to downgrade your Django version. But be advised that extended support for the last version of  Django 1.x (v1.11) ended in April 2022, and that all releases of Django 1.x before 1.11.17 only support Python 3.6 or below, which itself reached its end-of-life in December 2021.

If you want to go the route of upgrading your code to be compatible with modern versions of Django, the correct replacement for `smart_unicode` is `smart_str`. For help with this process, see

- [Python Docs - Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)
- [Django - Porting to Python 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/python3/)
- [Django - How to upgrade Django to a newer version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/upgrade-version/)
- [Django - Deprecation Timeline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#django-deprecation-timeline)
- [Django - Backwards incompatible changes in 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/2.0/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-2-0)
- [Django - Backwards incompatible changes in 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/3.0/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-3-0)
- [Django - Backwards incompatible changes in 4.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-4-0)

Comment: I will try your way and I will let you know. Thank you